# Facing Issue with Timespan in rest service serialization

Tags: json, wcf, rest, http-headers, httpresponse

I am using REST service to get the data from the Db.
In my class, I am having the property "UploadTime" of  datatype TimeSpan?.
The time span is calculated based on the difference between dates and in the response,I ma getting response as :

```
ArrayOfUploadUI xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NMS.ApplicationService.HIM.Objects" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <UploadUI>
  <UID>1</UID> 
  <DateCompleted>2015-01-08T10:46:25.25</DateCompleted> 
  <DateNotified>2015-01-07T10:46:25.25</DateNotified> 
  <DateDictationStartTime i:nil="true" /> 
  <DateDictationEndTime i:nil="true" /> 
  <UploadTime>P1D</UploadTime> 
  <ExistsOnBackend>false</ExistsOnBackend> 
  </UploadUI>
  </ArrayOfUploadUI>
```

.
I am getting the following exception while trying to get the data:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _HttpClient(session).GetAsync(apiUrl))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                else
                    await _HandleInvalidResponseAsync(response);
            }
```

I am getting issue at the  "response.Content.ReadAsAsync();".

Error is:

```
Error converting value "P1D" to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.TimeSpan]'. Path '[0].UploadTime', line 1, position 518.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType).
```

I googled and I came to know that WCF serilaizing the "timeSpan"datatype  from "1:0:0:00" to "P1D".

My issue is how to deserialize this on the response level.

Answer (score 0):

I have done formatting for the date at the source level and the issue got resolved.

```
JsonSerializerSettings dateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
            };
            string jsonNMSPlatformObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nmsPlatformObject,dateFormatSettings);
            using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonNMSPlatformObject))
            {
                httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(JsonMedaType);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, apiUrl);
                request.Content = httpContent;
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _HttpClient(session).SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return;
                    else
                        await _HandleInvalidResponseAsync(response, jsonNMSPlatformObject);
                }
            }
```